# Trying to find the average of EACH row in a 2d array

Tags: java

what i'm trying to do here is get the average of each row in my 2D array. Its only outputting the total -780- for the rawTotal when i want it to be 100 for the first row and yada yada...... can someone guide me in the correct direction on where to go from here?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at ArrayHW.averageRow(ArrayHW.java:40)
    at ArrayHW.main(ArrayHW.java:10)

public class ArrayHW {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int [][] a2 = {{10,20,30,40},
                {50, 60, 70 , 80},
                {90, 100, 110, 120}};
        display2DArray(a2);
        System.out.println(average2DArray(a2));
        System.out.println(min2DArray(a2));
        System.out.println(averageRow(a2));
    }

    public static int display2DArray(int[][] a2) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++){
                System.out.println(a2[row][column]);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static double average2DArray(int[][] a2) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < a2.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < a2[row].length; column++) {
                sum += a2[row][column];
                count++;
            }
        }
        return sum / count;
    }

    public static double averageRow(int[][] a2) {
        int rowTotal = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < a2.length; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < a2[row].length; column++){
                rowTotal += a2[row][column];

                //average = rowTotal / a2[row].length;
            }
        }
        return rowTotal;

    }
```

Comment: Start by placing `average = rowTotal / a2[row].length;` at the end of the outer loop (after the inner loop), but don't forget to reset the `rowTotal` before each iteration of the inner loop

Comment: Oh, and the first row's average isn't `100`, it's `25` (`100 / 4`)

Comment: yeah its coming out as 100...

Comment: So, do you want the average of the row or it's total, cause now I'm completed confused

Comment: I want the average of EACH row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of corrections to two of the methods. See the code comments for further explanation:

```
public static int display2DArray(int[][] a2) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++){
            System.out.print(a2[row][column] + " "); // better display
        }
        System.out.println(); // better display
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
public static double averageRow(int[][] a2) {
    int rowTotal = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < a2.length; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < a2[row].length; column++){
            rowTotal += a2[row][column];
        }
        average = rowTotal / a2[row].length; // calc average
        System.out.println(average); // print the row average
        rowTotal = 0; // start over (for next row)
    }
    return rowTotal;
}
```

Output of `averageRow`:

```
25.0
65.0
105.0
```

Comment: whats happening now is its displaying properly. except after 105.0 it has 0.0

Comment: Modify: `System.out.println(averageRow(a2));` to: `averageRow(a2);` - the method itself return zero which is getting printed...

Comment: Thank you @alfasin for showing me and putting comments to help me understood. Much appreciated

Comment: now what would be the difference for doing this with columns? @alfasin

Comment: @ThePyroMark that would be a good exercise, I recommend that you'll try to deal with it by yourself before looking for answers. There are a few different ways to do it, like switching the order of the for-loops ;)

Comment: ahh okay! @alfasin for (int column = 0; column < a2[row].length; column++) 'row' is error out and says row cannot be resolved to variable..

Comment: That's because `row` was not declared yet. But think about it - you don't really need it here - you can use instead: `a2[0].length`

Comment: right, because swapped the for-loops...but what i think is throwing me is im getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException and idk why @alfasin

Comment: I was able to get it! I screwed up when switched the for-loops. @alfasin Thank you very much, i really do appreciate you taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have multiple rows and you want to return some calculation on each of those rows, you need to return an array of values

This means you need to create an array in which the results of each rows calculation can be stored.  You also need to make sure that for each row, you are stating with a fresh set of values, for example...

```
public static double[] averageRow(int[][] a2) {

    double average[] = new double[a2.length];
    for (int row = 0; row < a2.length; row++) {
        int rowTotal = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < a2[row].length; column++) {
            rowTotal += a2[row][column];
        }

        average[row] = rowTotal / a2[row].length;
    }
    return average;

}
```

Then using something like...

```
int[][] a2 = {{10, 20, 30, 40},
{50, 60, 70, 80},
{90, 100, 110, 120}};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(averageRow(a2)));
```

Will output `[25.0, 65.0, 105.0]`